# Selective data extraction from forum site using DOM PHP web crawler

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler

I have this PHP dom web crawler which works fine. it extracts mentioned tag along with its link from a (external) forum site to my page.

But recently i ran into a problem.
Like

this is the HTML of the forum data::

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837880.php" target="_top" class="Links2">Hispanic Study Partner</a> - dreamer1984</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/28/17 01:42</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">0</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837879.php" target="_top" class="Links2">nbme</a> - monariyadh</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/27/17 23:12</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">0</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">108</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now if we consider the above code (table data) as the only statements available in that site. and if i tried to extract it with a web crawler like,

```
<?php
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.sitename.com/');
    foreach($html->find('td.FootNotes2') as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

It extracts al the data that is inside  with a class name as "FootNote2"

Now what if i want to extract specific data in  tag, 
for example names like, " dreamer1984" and "monariyadh" from the first  tag/line.

and what if i wanted to extract data from 3rd  (skipping the rest) which has same class names.

Hope i made the problem clear to understand.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to you use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

this is example of what you need

```
$subject = <<<EOF
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837880.php" target="_top" class="Links2">Hispanic Study Partner</a> - dreamer1984</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/28/17 01:42</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">0</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="/files/forum/2017/1/837879.php" target="_top" class="Links2">nbme</a> - monariyadh</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%" height="25" class="FootNotes2" align="center">02/27/17 23:12</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">0</td>
    <td width="1%" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="9%" height="25" align="Center" class="FootNotes2">108</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
EOF;

preg_match_all('/<td.+?FootNotes2.+?<a.+?<\/a> - (?P<name>.*?)<\/td>.+?<td.+?FootNotes2.+?(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})/siu', $subject, $matchs);

foreach ($matchs['name'] as $k => $v){
    var_dump('name: '. $v, 'relative date: '. $matchs['date'][$k]);
}
```

Comment: you need change my code, it's only an example.
Try this: `$subject = file_get_html('http://www.sitename.com/');`

Comment: I just replaced your code with mine. it prints out data as strings() numbers.. complete chaos...

Comment: I repeat it's only an example of code, now you need adapt it to your use case. Now you have `$matchs['name']` and his relative date in `$matchs['date']` Arrays. Try to use this arrays to your case

Comment: Dude, its dumb to ask more on this, but i m completely new to this, can you make one for me, will understand it and apply it for rest of my sites..

Comment: yeah sure, but i need an example of output what you want to have after the code parse the html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136878/discussion-between-harishk-and-vitaliy-ryaboy).